# Next Js & Babel causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, next.js

So I got things working where it babel compiles everything, including next.js

I followed next.js docs on how to handle babel and created a .babelrc file:

```
{
   "presets": ["next/babel", "es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

When I run `yarn run dev` everything compiles and the server starts. When I load a page, next.js will run it's build process. Since things in the directory change, nodemon restarts the server and causes an infinite loop. Can some help me with this please???

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "creatorsneverdie",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js --exec babel-node --ignore node_modules, .next, yarn.lock",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cryptr": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lowdb": "^0.16.2",
    "next": "^2.4.7",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

And the app.js file:

```
import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import passport from 'passport'


const db = require('./db/index.js').initDb()
const writeSeeds = require('./db/index.js').writeSeeds

const routes = require('./routes/index')

require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'});


// Next config
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const nextLoader = next({dev})
const handle = nextLoader.getRequestHandler()

nextLoader.prepare().then(() => {
    const app = express();

    app.use(cors());
    app.set('db', db);
    app.nextRender = nextLoader

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.use(session({
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }));

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    require('./config/passport')(passport);

    app.use('/', routes)

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    })

    // START APP
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);

    if(!db.has('products').value()) {
        writeSeeds(db);
    }
    const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
        console.log(`Express running -> ${server.address().port}`)
    });



})
```

Comment: Could you just use node instead of nodemon as you don't need nodemon restarting the server: `"dev": "node app.js --exec babel-node --ignore node_modules, .next, yarn.lock"`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I fixed that by adding *"pages/*"* to nodemon's ignore list. Somehow the build process is doing the pages source rewrite without changing anything which is then causing nodemon to restart and triggers the rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your dev script to:

```
nodemon -w app.js --exec babel-node
```